# I too want to wire a 3 phase motor to a VFD. And the question has already been asked but

Tags: vfd

[How to wire 3 phase motor to VFD](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/206972/how-to-wire-3-phase-motor-to-vfd)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmuB3.jpg

My Baldor vm3556t 1hp motor shows the same wiring as the photo above and the wires are bundled as shown on the low voltage side.
My Teco FM50 was hooked to this motor in the past but someone took it off to run a handheld router. 
Now I want to put it back to where it was but the diagram leaves me with a critical question; which of the three pair go to ground?

---

Woo Hoo!! You guys are awesome! I confess this is a freshman 101 student asking an advanced question with little understanding of the basics but:
The two machines in my description were dumpster rescues that used to be together. In the meanwhile someone had wired the VFD to a hand router by pulling the cord from the Baldor CLIPPING the red wire, and running green to ground. Must have worked for the hand router. Because your answer gave me the clue I went back to the manual, disassembled the cord, scratched my head, and followed instructions.
It worked!
It even spun in the right direction but that was luck.
I look forward to the day when I can answer a question.

Comment: It was asked at this link: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/206972/how-to-wire-3-phase-motor-to-vfd

Comment: NONE. If you connect any lead to the ground (except the housing) your VFD will smoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the three pair of motor leads (3-9, 2-8 & 1-7) are connected to ground. They are connected only to the three VFD output terminals. The group of three motor leads (6-5-4) are not connected to anything. They are just tied together and insulated. The frame of the motor and the VFD chassis or cabinet are connected to ground.

Comment: thanks, now I'll go read the forum rules so I won't leave you hanging next time.